# How to make SpringJUnit4ClassRunner honor db settings in persistence.xml , not application.properties?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test

I am using SpringBoot (1.2.5.RELEASE) . I like the style of defining persistence unit in `persistence.xml` (which contains db connection settings ) , and defining `entityManagerFactory` and `transactionManager` in a separate XML . (OK , this is traditional spring's setting. I just get used to it)

When running a spring boot , I define :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource({"classpath:consult.xml"})
public class ConsultApp {
}
```

And it works fine. PU / EMF / txMgr are OK.

But when I want to test spring beans. I find I have to re-define database settings in `application.properties` . This is my test class :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:consult.xml"})
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager= "consultTxMgr", defaultRollback=false)
@Configurable
public class ConsultTest {
}
```

I've assigned this `consult.xml` , but if I don't define `spring.datasource.*` in `application.properties` , it will report `Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' ...` error.

I don't know why the same XML file can work in spring-boot , but cannot work in spring-test . Why `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` cannot trace to the PU defined in the persistence.xml ?

Duplicate db settings in `persistence.xml` and `application.properties` is a bad smell. Is there any way to make spring-test honor the settings in `persistence.xml` ?

When executing test , I've seem it connecting to DB , messages about hibernate , tables are correctly logged.  But why it just need `datasource` defined !?

error log :

```
[main] WARN  o.s.c.s.GenericApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$JdbcTemplateConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$JdbcTemplateConfiguration.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined
```

Thanks.

Comment: When testing Spring Boot apps I have found `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` to be more reliable than `@ContextConfiguration`.  Try removing `@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:consult.xml"})` and `@Configurable` from your test class and add `@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = ConsultApp.class)` to it.